# How to resolve this PostgreSQL error on OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

Tags: macos, postgresql, installation, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I followed the instructions for setting up postgresql from [this site](http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2010/02/08/installing-ruby-on-rails-passenger-postgresql-mysql-oh-my-zsh-on-snow-leopard-fourth-edition)

All seems to go fine until I try:

> createuser --superuser myname -U
>   postgres

I get the following exception:

> createuser: could not connect to
>   database postgres: could not connect
>   to server: No such file or directory
>     Is the server running locally and
>   accepting     connections on Unix domain
>   socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

For the life of me I can't figure out how to resolve this.  Any ideas???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the existing postgres user before doing the install.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you moved your postgres data directory after you [installed postgres using macports](http://shifteleven.com/articles/2008/03/21/installing-postgresql-on-leopard-using-macports)

Find where your launchctl startup script is located.

```
ps -ef | grep postgres
```

Outputs

> 0    54     1   0   0:00.01 ??         0:00.01 /opt/local/bin/daemondo --label=postgresql84-server --start-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql84-server/postgresql84-server.wrapper start ; --stop-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql84-server/postgresql84-server.wrapper stop ; --restart-cmd /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql84-server/postgresql84-server.wrapper restart ; --pid=none

So I edit

```
sudo vim /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql84-server/postgresql84-server.wrapper
```

And find the line

```
Start()  {         
su postgres -c "${PGCTL} -D ${POSTGRESQL84DATA:=/opt/local/var/db/postgresql84/wrong_place}     start -l /opt/local/var/log/postgresql84/postgres.log"
```

}

Ahh.. my data directory is in the wrong place.  I fix it by changing

> /opt/local/var/db/postgresql84/wrong_place

to

> /opt/local/var/db/postgresql84/right_place

for both the start and stop command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `postgresql84-server` port? If so, did you start the server:

```
$ sudo port load postgresql84-server
```

If you did both of those, I've noticed that sometimes the MacPorts daemon handler (`daemondo`) doesn't start handling requests for PostgreSQL until you restart your machine. (This only happens the first time it is started; subsequent attempts should work fine.)

Comment: Tried the restart ... did not work. Ran "sudo port load postgresql84-server" ... got "Error: Target org.macports.load returned: org.macports.postgresql84-server: Already loaded
Error: Status 1 encountered during processing."