# Issue with conflicting postgres when using homebrew

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew, postgresql-9.2

I have an issue when attempting to use postgresql along with homebrew. After doing a completely clean install (and after upgrading from postgresql 9.1.3 to 9.2.4 and doing a system update of MacOS X) it appears that the postgresql that comes with Lion is conflicting with the one that homebrew provides.

The conflict means that when OSX launches (and with the ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist), postgresql fails to load properly at startup, which then causes the

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

error. The thing is, if I then manually load and unload the homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist agent, postgresql works from this point onwards, does anyone know how to fix this issue (I think it may be a conflict between /usr/bin/psql and the homebrew's /usr/local/bin/psql)

EDIT: after a fresh reboot and running `launchctl list | grep postgres`, I get this as a result `680  -   homebrew.mxcl.postgresql`, running `launchctl list | grep pg` gives nothing, and for some odd reason, it happens to be working now (even though I havn't changed anything after posting this). Will reboot a few more times to figure out what happened

EDIT2: It actually seems to work now, I have no idea why (wasted like 3 hours on it last night), I am going to mark this as answered until it comes back again

Comment: Run `launchctl list | grep postgres` and `launchctl list | grep pg` after rebooting, to see if another pg instance is being loaded. If so, `sudo launchctl unload [paste its name here].plist` it.

Comment: This appears to be an OSX-thing. Entering the last line of the error message will get you here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8465508/905902 (among others)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it was actually working, maybe something odd was happening in the boot sequence but postgres is now working fine, as expected, through homebrew