# Can't create postgres database from OSX terminal app

Tags: django, macos, postgresql, postgis

**Postgres Installation**
: I've used macports and followed the below command to install postgres. Here's the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#macports

```
    $ sudo port install postgresql83-server
```

**Unable to create database**
: When I try to create a database from the terminal application by using the below command

```
    $ createdb mydb
```

I get this error message

```
    createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Could you please help !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482546/905902 (OSX thingy) BTW: pg8.3 is very old. You should start by installing a later version such as 9.2 or 9.1

Comment: You should also consider using homebrew instead

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known issue on Mac OS X.

Apple bundle their own version of PostgreSQL with some OS X versions. This has a different default socket location. If Apple's `psql` and `libpq` are first on your `PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` then you'll be using old versions of the tools that default to Apple's locations for the socket.

You should fix your `PATH` so that the MacPorts `bin` dir is first, so the correct `psql` and `pg_config` are found first. Alternately you can probably just:

```
psql -h /tmp
```

or:

```
psql -h localhost
```

... but since using `psql` from a mismatched version can result in odd results, it'd much better to fix your `PATH`.

There's a lot more information on Stack Overflow about this, and a Google search for `"OS X" "postgresql" "could not connect to server: No such file or directory"` is rather informative.

Also: Please don't install PostgreSQL 8.3. it's outdated and unsupported. Install PostgreSQL 9.2, the current version. Why would you possibly use 8.3?

Comment: Hello Craig, Thanks for your advice, I've upgraded to version 9.2 with not much success. I am a novice in programming, could you please advice how I could fix the PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

Its telling you that the database isn't started. When you installed Postgres, macports told you to run a couple commands to initialize and start Postgres, and another (`launchctl ...`) to start Postgres when your computer starts. Did you run those?

If not see this post (change the file locations as needed):

https://shifteleven.com/articles/2008/03/21/installing-postgresql-on-leopard-using-macports/