# Rails ActiveRecord Connecting to Wrong Postgres Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

My database.yml is as follows:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: phunt_development
  username: <%= ENV['PG_USER'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['PG_PASS'] %>
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And I can confirm that the database phunt_development does exist.  However when I run `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.current_database` I get `development` not `phunt_development`.  I can't figure out why Rails is insisting on connecting to the general development database, which is polluted with data I have from other local apps.  I want to connect to `phunt_development`.

Comment: Have you restart your server/console after making changes in database.yml?

Comment: Yes I have multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue was a `$DATABASE_URL` variable was set in my environment.  When this is set, it overrides the configuration in `database.yml`.  Solution: run `unset DATABASE_URL`.