# can't connect to postgres server with mountain lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion

Need help after scouting all those issues with postgres and mac 10.8

I installed pg through homebrew (tried with heroku app also but no luck)

```
which psql --> /usr/local/bin/psql
psql --version --> psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4
```

When starting rails server I get `Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

When I do `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start` I get `server starting`

When I run `psql` I get `Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Any idea?

Comment: Can you check `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` or `/usr/local/var/postgres/*.log` for errors?

Comment: Can you check if the service is running? `ps aux | grep postgres` in linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482546/905902 possible duplicate

Comment: what does `which postgres` return and then what does `ls -l PATH_TO_POSTGRES` show - its possible it will still point to the factory installed version of postgres that comes with mac 10.8

Comment: @jallen7usa `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` does not exist because `/usr/local/var/postgres/` does not exist. @Vimsha looks like it's running since I get `username        16523   0,0  0,0  2432768    460 s000  R+    9:28     0:00.00 grep postgres`

Comment: @house9 `which postgres` returns `/usr/local/bin/postgres` which postgres. `ls -l /usr/local/bin/postgres
lrwxr-xr-x  1 olivier  admin  39 28 aoû 15:57 /usr/local/bin/postgres -> ../Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/bin/postgres`
@Vimsha looks like it's running since I get `username        16523   0,0  0,0  2432768    460 s000  R+    9:28     0:00.00 grep postgres` @jallen7usa `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` does not exist because `/usr/local/var/postgres/` does not exist

Comment: @olivier hmm perhaps your defaults are different. If you used the default plist to start your instance you can check there. Something like (but probably not exactly) this should show you the paths you're using: `cat /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever is wrong with my setup I ended adding `host: localhost`to my `database.yml`and it did the trick. Too much time wasted so it will remain as is for now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the user "postgres" in the system?

I don't know homebrew but maybe you need:

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Also postgres user must have write permissions on logs files.