# cannot restart postgres on mac os x

Tags: macos, postgresql

I cannot restart the postgres server on Mac OS X.
How can I fix this?

Tried two ways:

pg_ctl restart returns:

```
pg_ctl: PID file "usr/local/var/postgres:/postmaster.pid" does not exist
Is server running?
starting server anyway
pg_ctl: could not read file "usr/local/var/postgres:/postmaster.opts"
```

The server does not restart

pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres restart results in:

```
   pg_ctl: PID file "/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid" does not exist
   Is server running?
   starting server anyway
   server starting
   LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
   HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
   LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
   HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
   WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"
   FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

Comment: OMG .. yet another one... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482546/905902

Comment: Check for bogey running processes with `ps aux | grep postgres`, kill them and then try starting your server

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1 - Your `data` directory might be wrong.  Make sure you use the right path.**

**2 - If you install more than one postgres, you need to specify which `pg_ctl` to use.**

I installed postgres 9.2 manually, here's how I start it:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data start
```

I installed postgres 9.1 via HomeBrew, here's how it gets started:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.1.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres-9.1.5 start
```

Comment: But it needs postgresql user permission to run the first command [if install manually]