# Postgresql server will not start after OS X Yosemite upgrade, homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

**Steps to recreate error:**

- `brew uninstall postgresql`
- `brew prune`
- `brew install postgresql`
- run postgresql start commands
- `psql`

yields:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

**Suggested fixes I have tried that don't work:**

[create missing symbolic link:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)

- `sudo mkdir /var/pgsql_socket/`
- `sudo ln -s /private/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 /var/pgsql_socket/`

remove postmaster.pid file (same link as above):

- `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

[create potentially "cleaned up" directories from upgrade:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970132/pg-tblspc-missing-after-installation-of-os-x-yosemite)

- `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/
  touch /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/.keep`

[Related GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/14527)

**Edit 1:**

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147026/cannot-restart-postgres-on-mac-os-x) correctly speculates that there are multiple versions of postgres in use, and which `pg_ctl` must be specified (below). Strangely, there are two directories in `/usr/local/var`: `postgre` & `postgres`. If anybody knows which settings to update to use the proper `pg_ctl` command directly, I would appreciate it!

`/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.5_1/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgre start`

Comment: I'm getting similar issues in Yosemite, but reading through your description I suspect when you ran the start commands you neglected to copy the last character of a command ending in postgres like `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres` and somehow created an extraneous `postgre`.

Comment: this post solution worked for me `https://medium.com/@bitadj/completely-uninstall-and-reinstall-psql-on-osx-551390904b86`

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue and after looking at the log file I found one directory was missing:

```
$ tail /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_tblspc": No such file or directory
```

Then I did `$ mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_tblspc`, restarted PostgreSQL and got:

```
$ tail /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_replslot": No such file or directory
```

After redoing the process may times I eneded up creating the following directories and then successfully started PostgreSQL:

```
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_tblspc
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_replslot
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_twophase
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical
/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_logical/mappings
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Windows when trying to restore from a raw data backup. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me as well (using Mac OSX Catalina, Homebrew and Postgresql 12.3). There were a few additional folders & files to add but the same idea.